# Java Error: Can not find Symbol

Tags: javascript, java, compiler-errors, cannot-find-symbol

I've been working on this program for sometime now and I've been struggling with it. I'm new to programming so I don't understand how to fix it. So far I've managed to get rid of most of the errors but this one is the one I, for some reason, cannot fix. Can someone help me? I would really appreciate it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PetSorter
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Pet> strList = new ArrayList<Pet>();
    Boolean another = true;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(another)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the pet's name: ");
      String nam = keyboard.nextLine();
      Pet p = new Pet(nam); //here is where the Error occurs
      strList.add(p);

      System.out.println("Would you like to enter another pet's name? (y/n)");
      String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
      another = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
    }

    PetSorter.nameSort(strList);
    for (int x = 0; x < strList.size(); x++)
    {
      System.out.println(strList.get(x).getName());
    }
  }

  public static void nameSort (ArrayList<Pet> array)
  {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
      int j = i;
      Pet tp = array.get(i);
      String B = array.get(i).getName();
      while ((j > 0) && (array.get(j-1).getName().compareTo(B) > 0 ))
      {
        array.set(j, array.get(j-1));
        j--;
      }
      array.set(j,tp);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the pet class below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pet
{
    private String name;
    private int age; //in years
    private double weight; //in pounds

    /**
     This main is just a demonstration program.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pet myDog = new Pet( );
        myDog.set("Fido", 2, 5.5);
        myDog.writeOutput( );
        System.out.println("Changing name.");
        myDog.set("Rex");
        myDog.writeOutput( );
        System.out.println("Changing weight.");
        myDog.set(6.5);
        myDog.writeOutput( );
        System.out.println("Changing age.");
        myDog.set(3);
        myDog.writeOutput( );
    }

    public void writeOutput( )
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Age: " + age + " years");
        System.out.println("Weight: " + weight + " pounds");
    }

    public void set(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
        //age and weight are unchanged.
    }

    public void set(int newAge)
    {
        if (newAge <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: illegal age.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            age = newAge;
        //name and weight are unchanged.
    }

    public void set(double newWeight)
    {
        if (newWeight <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: illegal weight.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            weight = newWeight;
        //name and age are unchanged.
    }

    public void set(String newName, int newAge, double newWeight)
    {
        name = newName;
        if ((newAge <= 0) || (newWeight <= 0))
        {
            System.out.println("Error: illegal age or weight.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            age = newAge;
            weight = newWeight;
        }
    }

    public String getName( )
    {
        return name;
    }


    public int getAge( )
    {
        return age;
    }
    public double getWeight( )
    {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please share the full stack trace?

Comment: Is the Pet class in the same package as the PetSorter class?

Comment: Where is your `Pet` class?

Comment: @UUIIUI There you go. Sorry I forgot to put it in there

Comment: I have the pet class opened up in a separate file  but it still gives me this error. @Eran

Comment: I have the pet class opened up in a separate file but it still gives me this error. @Naytzyrhc

Comment: You still didn't write what error you get - which symbol can't be found. And you didn't answer my question regarding the packages.

Comment: Error: cannot find symbol                                                                      symbol: constructor Pet(java.lang.String)                                              location: class Pet  @Eran

Comment: please include the code of Pet class

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `Pet` class the required constrcutor :

```
public class Pet {

    String name;

    ...

    public Pet (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with

```
  Pet p = new PetSorter().new Pet(nam); //here is where the Error occurs
```

and add class Pet

new code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class PetSorter
{

public class Pet
{
    String name;

    public Pet(String _name)
    {
    name=_name; 
    }

    public String getName()
    {
    return name;
    }
}


  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    ArrayList<Pet> strList = new ArrayList<Pet>();
    Boolean another = true;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(another)
    {
  System.out.println("Enter the pet's name: ");
  String nam = keyboard.nextLine();

  Pet p = new PetSorter().new Pet(nam); //here is where the Error occurs
  strList.add(p);

  System.out.println("Would you like to enter another pet's name? (y/n)");
  String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
  another = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
    }

    PetSorter.nameSort(strList);
    for (int x = 0; x < strList.size(); x++)
    {
  System.out.println(strList.get(x).getName());
    }
  }

  public static void nameSort (ArrayList<Pet> array)
  {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
  int j = i;
  Pet tp = array.get(i);
  String B = array.get(i).getName();
      while ((j > 0) && (array.get(j-1).getName().compareTo(B) > 0 ))
      {
    array.set(j, array.get(j-1));
    j--;
      }
  array.set(j,tp);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pet p = new Pet(nam);` , `Pet` class doesn't have a constructor that takes any  arguments.